# FastJson encoder bug

Tags: .net, json, fastjson

I have a class Sale which holds sale data, and then i have a property in the Sale class which is A list of SaleItem class.

```
Sale
-date
-SaleItems <-- List(Of SaleItem)
-total
```

the SaleItem class

```
SaleItem
-productID
-amt
-qty
```

when I convert to Json string and debugged print to output. the SaleItems was not encoded,simply missing.

what am I doing wrong,or could this be a bug?

EDIT

The Sale class

```
Public Class Sale
    Private _Paid As Decimal
    Private _ListSaleItems As List(Of SaleItem)

    Public Sub New()
        ClearSaleItem()
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property SaleItems() As List(Of SaleItem)
        Get
            Return _ListSaleItems
        End Get
    End Property


    Public Property Paid() As Decimal
        Get
            Return _Paid
        End Get
        Set
            _Paid = value
        End Set
    End Property


    Public Sub ClearSaleItem()
        _ListSaleItems = New List(Of SaleItem)()
    End Sub


    Public Function AddSaleItem(value As SaleItem) As Decimal
        If value Is Nothing Then
            Throw New ApplicationException("SaleItem cannot be empty")
        End If
        _ListSaleItems.Add(value)
    End Function
End Class
```

The Saleitem Class

```
Public Class SaleItem
    Private _ID As Int32
    Private _Quantity As Int32
    Private _SellPrice As Decimal


    Public Sub New()
        _Quantity = 0
        _SellPrice = 0
    End Sub

    Public Property SellPrice() As Decimal
        Get
            Return _SellPrice
        End Get
        Set
            _SellPrice = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Quantity() As Int32
        Get
            Return _Quantity
        End Get
        Set
            _Quantity = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

The code i am using to convert is

```
sockClient.Send(fastJSON.JSON.ToJSON(ObjSales))
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Ok. It's not very helpful. Can you share a link to the lib fastJSON?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/159450/fastJSON

Comment: Can you share your full code (class and initialization)? I tried fastJSON and it works very well.

Comment: did you try is with a class say Sales with property SaleItems which is a list of another class Saleitem? If yes, can i see your code

Comment: Yes and Yes. I don't mind helping you but I want you to post your code. It will help you more in the future. Asking good, well formed and complete question is a skill. And I want you to get better at asking questions. This will help both of us to understand your problem. Also it could help every others viewers who would come here.

Comment: which code do you want to see, the code for the Sale class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your contribution, it happens that the dll coder gave me the solution

I have to change the Saleitems property of Sale from Readonly to Read/Write property

```
Public Property SaleItems() As List(Of SaleItem)
            Get
                Return Me.listSaleItems
            End Get
Set(value as List(Of SaleItem))
                listSaleItems = value 
            End Get
        End Property
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is my working code (in C# not VB) to justify that this is not a bug from the lib :

```
namespace TestFastJson
{
    internal class Program
    {
            private static void Main()
            {
                    var sale = new Sale
                    {
                        SaleItems = new List<SaleItem>
                        {
                            new SaleItem(),
                            new SaleItem()
                        }
                    };

                    string jsonText = fastJSON.JSON.ToJSON(sale);

                    var newobj = fastJSON.JSON.ToObject<Sale>(jsonText);

                    Console.WriteLine(newobj.SaleItems.Count);
            }
    }

    public class Sale
    {
            public DateTime Date { get; set; }
            public List<SaleItem> SaleItems { get; set; }
            public int Total { get; set; }
    }

    public class SaleItem
    {
            public string ProductId { get; set; }
            public int Amount { get; set; }
            public string Quality { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Output

```
2
```

Now for your code. Why `AddSaleItem()` returns a `Decimal`?
And `SaleItems` is missing because `SaleItems` is set as `private`. Switch to `public` and here it is. If the setter is not accessible how the lib could set the value?

Your code with a valid output:

```
    Friend Class Program
        Private Shared Sub Main()
            Dim sale = New Sale()
            sale.AddSaleItem(New SaleItem())
            sale.AddSaleItem(New SaleItem())

            Dim jsonText As String = fastJSON.JSON.ToJSON(sale)

            Console.WriteLine(jsonText)

            Dim newobj = fastJSON.JSON.ToObject(Of Sale)(jsonText)
            Console.WriteLine(newobj.SaleItems.Count)
        End Sub
    End Class

    Public Class SaleItem
        Private _ID As Int32

        Public Sub New()
            Me.Quantity = 0
            Me.SellPrice = 0
        End Sub

        Public Property SellPrice() As Decimal
            Get
                Return m_SellPrice
            End Get
            Set
                m_SellPrice = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_SellPrice As Decimal
        Public Property Quantity() As Integer
            Get
                Return m_Quantity
            End Get
            Set
                m_Quantity = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_Quantity As Integer
    End Class

    Public Class Sale
        Public listSaleItems As List(Of SaleItem)
        Public Sub New()
            Me.ClearSaleItem()
        End Sub

        Public ReadOnly Property SaleItems() As List(Of SaleItem)
            Get
                Return Me.listSaleItems
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Property Paid() As Decimal
            Get
                Return m_Paid
            End Get
            Set
                m_Paid = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_Paid As Decimal

        Public Sub ClearSaleItem()
            Me.listSaleItems = New List(Of SaleItem)()
        End Sub

        Public Sub AddSaleItem(value As SaleItem)
            If value Is Nothing Then
                Throw New ApplicationException("SaleItem cannot be empty")
            End If
            Me.listSaleItems.Add(value)
        End Sub
    End Class
```

Output

```
2
```